# MySql Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect with `Mysql` using `PHP`. It works fine when I do it without a database. But gives me the following error when I try to connect with a database.

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_test' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Projects\DemoProject\demo2.php on line 13
>   Connection failed: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'db_test'

My `PHP` code is given below.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "";
$dbname = "db_test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else 
    echo "Connected Successfully";
?>
```

Comment: does the user have the assigned rights to access this database? does the database exists? btw, The default user in xampp is `root` with no password.

Comment: yes. the database exists. But I am not sure whether the user has the right to access the database. Ho to check it out or how to give the access?

Comment: try running mysql -u root -p from cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used the wrong username. To check the username and servername just run the query given below-

```
select CURRENT_USER();
```

In general, username set as `root` and server name set as `localhost` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the user with your username and pass with your password for database and run the below command grant and flush privileges from root user.

```
grant all privileges on db_test.* to 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'pass';

flush privileges;
```